# settype changes the value of session variables

Tags: php, session, casting

I've a session variable initialized as `$_SESSION["total"]=0`. I am trying to get the value of it by using the `settype()` function. But, it echoes the value as 1. My code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["total"]=0;
$session_val = settype($_SESSION["total"],"integer");
echo $session_val; //this outputs 1 rather than 0
$session_val = (int)$_SESSION["total"];
echo $session_val; //this outputs 0 correctly
?>
```

So, while casting through `(int)` produces the correct result why using `settype` changes the value of it?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran this is only a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`settype()`](https://www.php.net/settype) returns a boolean, not the actual value itself. The `1` you are seeing is the boolean output `TRUE`.

The following code should do what you want:

```
$_SESSION["total"] = 0;    
$session_val = $_SESSION["total"];

$ok = settype($session_val,"integer");

if ($ok) {
    echo $session_val; // => 0
}
```

Although not related to the actual issue, you'd want to add `session_start()` at the very top of your script if you are going to deal with sessions.